# Did I accidentally corrupt the filesystem using VIM and Netrw?

Tags: macos, vim, filesystems

I am using Mac OS X.

I accidentally did the following:

```
vim /path/to/directory
```

I meant to open a file, but instead I opened a directory. VIM was excessively helpful, so it opened Netrw. I did not know what Netrw was at the time. I tried to quit using colon-q, but that made all sorts of weird things happen. Then it said **recording** in bold on the bottom, and I continued trying to quit. Eventually it gave me the option to use the arrow keys to get to :q!, so I selected that, and it quit.

Very worryingly, the mtime of the directory was modified. I did not modify the contents of the directory at that time (not intentionally), but the mtime was modified.

Did I corrupt the filesystem? When I exited Netrw, it did not say "XXX bytes written". In fact, it said nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Although netrw does allow you to delete and rename files I doubt you did anything harmful, since netrw prompts you for any potentially destructive action.

The "recording" message you got was from the "macro recording" feature of Vim. See:

```
:help recording
```

Although the directory modified time changing does concern me.  If it were a local directory I would say it's because Vim tried to create a "swap" file for recovery purposes.

Comment: It was a local directory. I tried reenacting the mistake, and my reenactments never touch the mtime and they never create a swap file. However, the swap file seems extremely likely.

Is it possible that I corrupted the filesystem in some pernicious way? Could I have done something worse than deleting or renaming contents of the directory? Could I have changed the Apple flags and now Time Machine won't work, for instance? I am definitely being paranoid, but sometimes paranoia is justified.

Comment: Also, vim has been my favorite CLI text editor for like 8 years. How did I just learn about recording today? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think netrw could do all that--as far as I know netrw doesn't even have the ability to change file permissions.  Which directory was it?

Comment: It was a very normal vanilla directory with important text files. I may have forgotten which directory at this point. Thanks for the help.